# Detecting files that failed to load while testing with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, web, webdriver

If you open your dev tools while a page is loading, you'll see all the json/js/fonts/images/etc files that loaded while the page loaded.

I want to be able to detect if any of these failed to load, while executing my Selenium WebDriver tests.

I'm pretty sure WebDriver doesn't support seeing these individual http requests, but what approach should I take to be able to detect any that fail to load? Keep in mind that all my testing is behind a login.

Comment: Check the log form the browser. If a resource fails to load, the browser will report the error.

Comment: You might need to use tool for network traffic monitoring, like `WireShark` or something, and parse its output to detect requests that return `4XX`, `5XX` code statuses... I guess:)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class containing all the file URLs, do a CURL against it, and compare the return code to see if they return a 200 or whatever.

I don't know which language are you using, but maybe this helps you:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log